# Samba shadow_copy2 snapshots not showing up in Windows Previous Versions?

Tags: windows-8.1, samba, file-sharing, shadow-copy, previous-versions

I'm using Samba 4.5 with ZFS as a file share to a Windows 8.1 client. Samba itself is working and I've tested my smb.conf using `testparm` - it looks correct. The smbd log doesn't show any errors. But I'm not seeing any Previous Versions in the client.

I'm not sure where to go with this, to figure what I'm missing and what's needed to fix it.

Output of `testparm`:

```
[global]
        domain master = Yes
        lm announce = Yes
        os level = 200
        preferred master = Yes
        logging = file
        max log size = 51200
        reject md5 clients = Yes
        async smb echo handler = Yes
        kernel change notify = No
        panic action = /usr/local/libexec/samba/samba-backtrace
        pid directory = /var/run/samba
        disable spoolss = Yes
        load printers = No
        printcap name = /dev/null
        max mux = 500
        name resolve order = wins host bcast
        server min protocol = SMB3_02
        time server = Yes
        auth methods = sam
        map to guest = Bad User
        security = USER
        server role = standalone server
        username level = 5
        deadtime = 30
        hostname lookups = Yes
        keepalive = 45
        max open files = 2826902
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072
        reject md5 servers = Yes
        dns proxy = No
        wins hook = ***
        wins support = Yes
        case sensitive = Yes
        map archive = No
        store dos attributes = Yes
        strict locking = No
        directory name cache size = 0
        dos filemode = Yes
        acl allow execute always = Yes
        map acl inherit = Yes
        access based share enum = Yes
        admin users = ***
        create mask = ***
        directory mask = ***
        hosts allow = ***
        hosts deny = ***
        write cache size = 524288

[Test_share]
        path = "***"
        hide dot files = No
        veto files = /.snapshot/.windows/.zfs/
        invalid users = ***
        read only = No
        vfs objects = zfs_space zfsacl streams_xattr aio_pthread shadow_copy2
        shadow:sort = asc
        shadow:fixinodes = yes
        shadow:format = _%Z-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S
        shadow:delimiter = _
        shadow:snapprefix = ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+
        shadow:snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
        zfsacl:acesort = dontcare
        nfs4:chown = true
        nfs4:acedup = merge
        nfs4:mode = special
        recycle:subdir_mode = 0700
        recycle:directory_mode = 0777
        recycle:touch = yes
        recycle:versions = yes
        recycle:keeptree = yes
        recycle:repository = .recycle/%U
```

Sample output of `zfs list -t snapshots`

```
Test_pool/***@cronjob-15m_UTC-2017.10.13-00.00.00                      0      -    88K  -
Test_pool/***@cronjob-15m_UTC-2017.10.13-00.15.00                      0      -    88K  -
Test_pool/***@cronjob-15m_UTC-2017.10.13-00.30.00                      0      -    88K  -
Test_pool/***@cronjob-15m_UTC-2017.10.13-00.45.00                      0      -    88K  -
Test_pool/***@cronjob-15m_UTC-2017.10.13-01.00.00                      0      -    88K  -
Test_pool/***@cronjob-15m_UTC-2017.10.13-01.15.00                      0      -    88K  -
```

Sample output of `grep shadow -C 5 log.smbd | tail -n 300`:

```
doing parameter zfsacl:acesort = dontcare
doing parameter invalid users = ***
doing parameter vfs objects = zfs_space zfsacl streams_xattr aio_pthread shadow_copy2
doing parameter shadow:snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
doing parameter shadow:snapprefix = ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+
doing parameter shadow:delimiter = _
doing parameter shadow:format = _%Z-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S
doing parameter shadow:fixinodes = yes
doing parameter shadow:sort = asc
[2017/10/14 17:08:16.429943,  4, pid=39112, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3866(lp_load_ex)
pm_process() returned Yes
[2017/10/14 17:08:16.429982,  7, pid=39112, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4185(lp_servicenumber)
lp_servicenumber: couldn't find homes
[2017/10/14 17:08:16.430016,  3, pid=39112, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:1587(lp_add_ipc)

--- AND ---

Load smb config files from /usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
Processing section "[Test_share]"
Loaded services file OK.

smbd_marshall_dir_entry: space_remaining = 65528
[2017/10/14 17:07:33.867623, 10, pid=39112, effective(0, 65533), real(0, 0)] ../source3/smbd/trans2.c:2231(smbd_marshall_dir_entry)
smbd_marshall_dir_entry: SMB_FIND_ID_BOTH_DIRECTORY_INFO
[2017/10/14 17:07:33.867644,  6, pid=39112, effective(0, 65533), real(0, 0)] ../source3/smbd/dir.c:1136(smbd_dirptr_get_entry)
smbd_dirptr_get_entry: dirptr 0x8120420e0 now at offset 2147483648
[2017/10/14 17:07:33.867663, 10, pid=39112, effective(0, 65533), real(0, 0)] ../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:609(shadow_copy2_strip_snapshot_internal)
../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:609: enter path '***/..'
[2017/10/14 17:07:33.867680, 10, pid=39112, effective(0, 65533), real(0, 0)] ../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:618(shadow_copy2_strip_snapshot_internal)
../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:618: abs path '/***'
[2017/10/14 17:07:33.867701,  8, pid=39112, effective(0, 65533), real(0, 0)] ../source3/smbd/dosmode.c:616(dos_mode)
dos_mode: ***/..
[2017/10/14 17:07:33.867719, 10, pid=39112, effective(0, 65533), real(0, 0)] ../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:609(shadow_copy2_strip_snapshot_internal)
../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:609: enter path '***/..'
[2017/10/14 17:07:33.867734, 10, pid=39112, effective(0, 65533), real(0, 0)] ../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:618(shadow_copy2_strip_snapshot_internal)
../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:618: abs path '/***'
[2017/10/14 17:07:33.867754,  5, pid=39112, effective(0, 65533), real(0, 0)] ../source3/smbd/dosmode.c:287(get_ea_dos_attribute)
get_ea_dos_attribute: Cannot get attribute from EA on file ***/..: Error = Attribute not found
[2017/10/14 17:07:33.867771,  5, pid=39112, effective(0, 65533), real(0, 0)] ../source3/smbd/dosmode.c:70(dos_mode_debug_print)
dos_mode_debug_print: dos_mode_from_sbuf returning (0x10): "d"
[2017/10/14 17:07:33.867786,  5, pid=39112, effective(0, 65533), real(0, 0)] ../source3/smbd/dosmode.c:70(dos_mode_debug_print)
```

It all looks right, but I'm not seeing Previous Versions in the client, so it's clearly not quite there.

What might be missing?

Comment: Hey @Stilez, have you by any chance had any progress with that issue?

Comment: Nope.  No luck at all